# node HTTP-Server is not working properly?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

when i install http-server in c: drive it install automatically in d: drive.

here is the result:-

```
C:\Users\Kuncham>npm install http-server -g
D:\usr\local\http-server -> D:\usr\local\node_modules\http-server\bin\http-server
D:\usr\local\hs -> D:\usr\local\node_modules\http-server\bin\http-server
+ http-server@0.11.1
updated 1 package in 1.131s
```

after installation when i run http-server in my project folder it will start the http-server and also we can access the link given in command prompt. the browser will show only files not run the my angular application. [image]

Comment: Have you done an `ng build`? You might be interested in (re-)reading [Angular - Deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment).

Comment: we are in developement process so we just want to check in our local systems

Comment: What? You need to build your angular project in order to generate browser-consumable HTML and Javascript.

Comment: so there is no way to check without ng build ?

Comment: Lots of Angular-based constructs are not supported by browsers without first being compiled to vanilla HTML and Javascript. How have you been viewing/testing your project so far?

Comment: thanks for your time. but we are new in angular . we just trying things on our best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform an `ng build` on the directory and point your `http-server` at the resulting `dist/` folder, which contains the compiled HTML and Javascript files your browser can consume.

More information: [Angular - Deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

Answer (score 3):

1. Install http-server using **npm install -g http-server** command
2. Generate a build by using **ng build --prod** command
3. Go to **dist/project_name** from cmd
4. Type **http-server -p 8080** on cmd
5. Type **http://localhost:8080/** on browser

Answer (score 1):

I just installed http-server today and my problem was it just wasn't serving the content at all when I went to localhost:8080. The command prompt would flash for a second and disappear. I resolved my problem by hitting http://192.168.40.78:8080. http-server lists two urls you could hit. The 192 one worked, but not the localhost one.

Answer (score -2):

specify the file when running `http-server`

```
http-server [path] [options]

[path] defaults to ./public if the folder exists, and ./ otherwise.
```

Comment: i did used http-server ./